# Infinite recursion trying to resolve type in custom DI container

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have a issue with this container I'm using. It works fine when I register a service with it implementation. But when I'm registering just a implementation it goes to Stackoverflow Exception

> cause it calls over and over the GetIntance method in the initial
>   check for an registered type.

How I can solve this?

```
public class DIContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _registeredTyped = new Dictionary<Type, Func<objec>>();

    public void Register<I, C>()
    {
        _registeredTypes.Add(typeof(I), () => GetInstance(typeof(C)));
    }

    public void RegisterSinglenton<T>(T obj)
    {
        _registeredTypes.Add(typeof(T), () => obj);
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        if (_registeredTypes.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return _registeredTypes[type]();
        }
        var constructor = type.GetConstructors().OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length).First();
        var args = constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => GetInstance(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've provided an answer to your question, but I believe that (unless this is just for the learning experience) you should stick to using a tried and tested container such as Autofac, Ninject, Castle Windsor, Microsoft's DependencyInjection (as used in ASP.NET Core), etc.

Comment: Actually I'm using it in a small project basically for a better understanding of the IoC and DI concepts and implementations. You were very helpful thank you.

Comment: Side note: please read [MCVE] guidance - the code you've posted is longer than necessary and clearly not related to DI part of the code. Indeed it is a reasonable idea to add code/details why you are facing the problem *in addition* to the smallest code that shows the problem.

Comment: Trolling: DI and reflection is something I'd expect one to learn after they get basics of debugging... You may want to read through questions about stack overflows and debug the code to answer them without looking at answers … (This is non-welcoming/unkind suggestion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a type, you add a `Func` delegate to your `_registeredTypes` dictionary:

```
_registeredTypes.Add(typeof(I), () => GetInstance(typeof(C)));
```

So if you take `Func<Test> testFactory = _registeredTypes[typeof(Test)];`, and then call it (`testFactory();`), it will make a call to `GetInstance` to actually obtain the instance.

Now let's take a look at the part of `GetInstance` that looks this object up:

```
    if (_registeredTypes.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        return _registeredTypes[type]();
    }
```

So your code is obtaining the factory from `_registeredTypes` using the key `type`, and then it calls the factory method to return the instance. The factory method calls `GetInstance` for the same type, which obtains the factory from `_registeredTypes` using the key `type`, and then it calls the factory method to return the instance. The factory method calls `GetInstance` for the same type, which obtains the factory from `_registeredTypes` using the key `type`, and then it calls... etc.

As you can see, you'll forever go around in a loop of looking up the type's factory in the dictionary, calling the factory method, which in turn calls the very same `GetInstance` method, until the stack is full and your application crashes.

To solve this you can separate the `GetInstance`into two methods: one for creating instances, one for resolving instances through the `_registeredTypes` dictionary:

```
public object GetInstance(Type type)
{
    if (_registeredTypes.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        return _registeredTypes[type]();
    }
    else
    {
        return null; // or throw an exception, etc.
    }
}

public object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    var constructor = type.GetConstructors().OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length).First();
    var args = constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => GetInstance(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
}
```

And then you can change your `Register` method to use `CreateInstance`:

```
public void Register<I, C>()
{
    _registeredTypes.Add(typeof(I), () => CreateInstance(typeof(C)));
}
```

Also, some advice: consider the scenario where TypeA requires TypeB requires TypeA. This will also lead to a StackOverflowException. As an improvement, you might want to detect this before it leads to a crash, and throw your own exception.

Comment: Thank you! How do you think that the Cross reference issue could be resolved?

Comment: Ideally by not writing code against the container that has that kind of circular dependency. Using Lazy<T> could be one approach if it ever is necessary to have this kind of relationship. You could look at how other containers handle this kind of problem.